# ORACLE Cannot see apostrophes in my data, when read from SQL DEVELOPER

Tags: oracle, character-encoding, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to export a large amount of data from a Oracle DB.
One of the field contains a long string. This field is a VARCHAR2 (2000 chars).
For some reason a string like **Mark's dog** is shown (and exported) as **Mark s dog**
Pay attention! Space before the s char, is not a space... is an invisibile char that some editor see as PU2, but I cannot replace it.

Is there a reason for this issue? The production site (not one of mine...) shows the single quote correctly... so it's there somehow.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what "PU2" stands for here.  Are we talking about an actual apostrophe?  Or the Microsoft curly apostrophe (0x92 in Windows-1252 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)?  What are the character sets of the databases?  How are you exporting the data?  What character set do you expect the file to be in?

Comment: @JustinCave - It seems an actual apostrophe, but I have no deep access to the DB, so I'm not sure. I can only see that Oracle SLQ Developer does not display it and, once exported (CSV, XML, XLSX,... the char is rendered in a bad way)

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look, here's a scenario - I hope it's close to yours.

```
set sqlformat ansiconsole
drop table missing_quotes purge;
clear screen

create table missing_quotes
 (id integer,
 words varchar2(2000));
 
insert into missing_quotes values
 (1, 'Mark''s dog');
 
 insert into missing_quotes values
 (2, 'Shelly''s cat');
 
select * from missing_quotes;
```

And the output -

```
Table MISSING_QUOTES created.


1 row inserted.


1 row inserted.


ID   WORDS          
    1 Mark's dog      
    2 Shelly's cat
```

Now let's do the export. You're not saying how, but we'll just export the query results...as INSERT statements.

[image]

And our output -

```
REM INSERTING into MISSING_QUOTES
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into MISSING_QUOTES (ID,WORDS) values (1,'Mark''s dog');
Insert into MISSING_QUOTES (ID,WORDS) values (2,'Shelly''s cat');
```

Or CSV -

```
"ID","WORDS"
1,"Mark's dog"
2,"Shelly's cat"
```

Everything appears to be OK, including the apostrophe in your VARCHAR2(2000).

Comment: First of all I have to say that this is the first time I work with Oracle... so my reply can be silly.
I tried to export data in serveral ways: XML, XLSX, CSV... actually I did not tried INSERT.
I can access this DB only remotely, via VPN access, and I really don't know how the original developer inserted all the data. I can only see that the output of the original site shows the apostrophe correctly. 
I'll try to export my data as INSERT. I'll give you a feedback soon... I hope! :/

Comment: Sure, understood...we just need a test case, otherwise you're asking us to guess. It's more likely your data is already bad in the database.